# .htaccess conditional 410 with special characters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-410

Our website was recently hacked with spam content, and going through the cleanup process I'd like to create 410 rewrites for them.

The URLs in question are top level, so can't specify by directory, but the bulk of the bad URLs include == at the end. For example:

www.example.com/ci0yMTQ2LTUvMTQ5NzcteA==

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work and struggling to find a way where special characters can be included.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ==

RewriteRule .* - [G,L]

Cheers!

Comment: Why would this need a RewriteCond to begin with? A RewriteRule can check the path component of the URL directly. `RewriteRule ==$ - [G,L]`

Comment: Bingo. Simple and perfect, thanks!